# OledbException Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, vb.net, type-mismatch

I'm getting a `OledbException Data type mismatch in the criteria expression`, at  `ad.Fill(xDataset, "TblMaster")`.

I'm using an Access database and Telerik Reporting.

This is my code

```
Public Sub TanggalX()

    conn.Open()

    Dim str9 As String = "Select * From TblMaster Where Tanggal='" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) & "'"
    ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(str9, conn)
    xDataset.Clear()
    ad.Fill(xDataset, "TblMaster")
    obj_RepDoc = New Report1
    obj_RepDoc.DataSource = (xDataset)
    Me.ReportViewer1.Report = obj_RepDoc
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Me.Show()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Please help me this is my last problem for this project.

Answer (score 3):

You should use # instead of ' for Date/Time fields.

```
 Dim str9 As String = "SELECT * FROM TblMaster WHERE Tanggal=#" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `TblMaster.Tangall` is of type `Date` and you are specifying it as a `string` in the `WHERE` clause of your `SQL` select command.

Try the following:

```
using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
{
    var parameter =comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tangall", Me.DateTimePicker1.Value);
    parameter.OleDbType = OleDbType.DBDate;

        using (var ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm))
        {
            ... //do your stuff here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think InBetween is right. You can also convert the string to date inside the SQL statement instead of using parameters by replacing your SQL statement with this:

```
Dim str9 As String = "Select * From TblMaster Where Tanggal=CDate('" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() & "')"
```